# cv::namedWindow() crashed, Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opencv, gdb

This is a stochastic problem. When I re-make my project, this problem is more likely to happen. I used gdb core dump analysis and found out that `cv::namedWindow` function may be the reason?

This is main.cpp

```
Simple_ORB_SLAM::Map map;
Simple_ORB_SLAM::LocalMapping localMapper(&map);
Simple_ORB_SLAM::VisualOdometry vo(&localMapper, &euroc, &map);
Simple_ORB_SLAM::Viewer viewer(&euroc, &map, &vo);

std::thread* tViewer = new std::thread(&Simple_ORB_SLAM::Viewer::Run, &viewer);
std::thread* tMapper = new std::thread(&Simple_ORB_SLAM::LocalMapping::Run, &localMapper);
```

This is Viwer::Run() function.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//set menu
pangolin::CreatePanel("menu").SetBounds(0.0,1.0,0.0,pangolin::Attach::Pix(175));
pangolin::Var<bool> menuFollowCamera("menu.Follow Camera",true,true);
pangolin::Var<bool> menuShowPoints("menu.Show Points",true,true);
pangolin::Var<bool> menuShowKeyFrames("menu.Show KeyFrames",true,true);

//set camera
pangolin::OpenGlRenderState s_cam(pangolin::ProjectionMatrix(1024,768, mpCamera->mViewpointF,mpCamera->mViewpointF,512,389,0.1,1000),pangolin::ModelViewLookAt(mpCamera->mViewpointX,mpCamera->mViewpointY,mpCamera->mViewpointZ, 0,0,0,0.0,-1.0, 0.0) );

//set view
pangolin::View& d_cam = pangolin::CreateDisplay()
        .SetBounds(0.0, 1.0, pangolin::Attach::Pix(175), 1.0, -1024.0f/768.0f)
        .SetHandler(new pangolin::Handler3D(s_cam));

//set transform mat
pangolin::OpenGlMatrix Twc;
Twc.SetIdentity();

//set opencv window
cv::namedWindow("Simple_ORB_SLAM: Current Frame");




while(!pangolin::ShouldQuit())
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    d_cam.Activate(s_cam);

    //set background
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    DrawCurrCamera();

    if(menuShowPoints)
        DrawMapPoints();

    if(menuShowKeyFrames)
        DrawKeyFrames();

    pangolin::FinishFrame();    
}
```

And I show image in the construct funtion of class Frame

```
...

//show orb feature map
cv::imshow("Simple_ORB_SLAM: Current Frame",imgLeft);
cv::waitKey(250/mpCamera->fps);
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDg2O.png) this is gdb traceback

This is my first time using gdb and stackoverflow, sorry about the fuzzy description of my problem. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: It is impossible to reason about a random segfault without seeing the code and knowing at what point it occurs

Comment: my fault, I have updated my problem description and added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not open a `cv::namedWindow` from a thread that isn't the main thread. It might work, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: yes that's right. I delete it and everything is ok. Thank you very much !!! But I can't figure out why I should not open it in another thread? I guess maybe some low level implement of opencv?

Comment: This is not a OpenCV specific thing. From my experience in Windows, UI elements need to be created and maintained from the main thread. OpenCV doesn't have an inbuilt UI framework, it just calls WinAPI (for Windows) and has the same limitation.